# No route to host from control plane node on bare metal kubernetes

Tags: routing, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, bare-metal

I am running a kubernetes cluster composed of three nodes. Control plane node is running inside an Azure VM, and two worker nodes on two separate bare-metal servers. I have set up the cluster with `kubeadm` and two worker nodes joined without issues. I installed weave as CNI and spawning pods and creating deployments works fine. I reached issues when I tried to set up nginx ingress for external access. When applying this manifest

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-example
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: demo
            port:
              number: 80
```

I get the following error: `Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ingress.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1/ingresses?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.98.59.50:443: connect: no route to host`.

After inspecting the issue, I also realized that whenever I try to curl any cluster IP address (e.g., `curl 10.32.0.9`), I get this error: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.32.0.9 port 80 after 3056 ms: No route to host`.

After googling a bit, it seems that the issue was something with firewalls. I enabled all inbound and outbound ports on azure portal, but the issue still persists.